# Previous to page with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have a SPA system and to do the routes I am using the ui-router $stateProvider.state and this case the browser not save the history to that I can return to last page, I tried many things and didn't work yet, in this case I need that when the user clicked in Cancel button he return to last page, How I do this?

Comment: Can you share the states that you have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event on `stateChangeSuccess` to keep in memory your last state:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
   /* Here, from is the previous page you want to recover */
   /* For example: */
   $state.previousState = from;
});
```

You will be able to use it in `$state.go`:

```
$state.go($state.previousState.name);
```

---

*Note: using `stateChangeStart` may work as well.*

Comment: This event I put in the cancel button click?

Comment: @DiogoSoares Nope, it is a general event, I suggest you  to put it in your `app.run()`.

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Thank you so much
Just one think the command is "$state.previousState.name"